# Is there a native PHP function for grabbing (and unsetting) an array element?

Tags: php, arrays

I just wondered if there were an native PHP function that would replicate the following snippet?

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'element1', 1 => 'element2');
$element1 = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);
?>
```

Basically, I wish to grab an array element but unset that particular key at the same time. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't be afraid to write your own functions, it's OK. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`array_splice()`](http://de3.php.net/array_splice) to extract elements from any position but the way you mention in your question is probably more efficient than that.

Answer (score 1):

For a certain cases:

- [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) / Pop the element off the end of array
- [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) / Shift an element off the beginning of array

General version:

- [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) / Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else

Answer (score 0):

[`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) removed the first item of an array:

```
$array = array(0 => 'element1', 1 => 'element2');
$element1 = array_shift($array);
```

But it also reindexes the array so that the remaining array would be equal to:

```
$array = array('element2');
```